# Android Studio can't extract layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a complete beginner and following a guide. it asked me to click anywhere on my vertical layout and refractor -> refract this -> extract layout but as you can see in the screenshot all my options are greyed out
and the only option that I get in refactor this is "remove unused resources"

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vkeh7m1gs5zmeek/Screenshot%202017-06-23%2018.55.37.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/71v1b3nc2ysqk0t/Screenshot%202017-06-23%2022.46.12.png?dl=0

Comment: Where have you clicked for that option menu?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/71v1b3nc2ysqk0t/Screenshot%202017-06-23%2022.46.12.png?dl=0   I guess I mentioned this. Clicking anywhere doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are clicking on the LinearLayout Element on the Left side, Guide says to click anywhere inside vertical layout.
Try right clicking on the vertical layout in Design View.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/71v1b3nc2ysqk0t/Screenshot%202017-06-23%2022.46.12.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

In the preview screen, click on the layout you want to extract.
Then choose *Refactor* and *Extract style*.
[image: Extracting Android Layout]

You can save the layout in camelCase or in lowercase.

Note: **You should not start layout names with captial letters.**

[image: Saving the extracted layout with the name reUsableLayout.xml]

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere in the vertical layout means any elements inside the design window. But not inside the `Component Tree`. That means click anywhere inside the red marked area.

[image]

Comment: Dude I know that and I mentioned both ways in the question. I posted the screenshot of the component tree one. Here is what I get from refactor this

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/71v1b3nc2ysqk0t/Screenshot%202017-06-23%2022.46.12.png?dl=0

Comment: how do you Get a preview of images in your questions or answers?